# vba Excel: Same parameters for several shapes - LIST instead of WITH

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, shapes

I  have 8 rectangles in a worksheet. 4 have the same size and the other 4 also the same size (thus 2 groups of rectangles, each group with another size). My code looks like this so far (cutout for 2 rectangles of the same size):

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Nut As Shape
Dim Nut2 As Shape
Dim Nutbreite As Double
Dim Nutbreite2 As Double

Nutbreite = (Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("C3").Value)
    Set Nut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Shapes("Gruppieren 10")
    With Nut
        .Width = Nutbreite
        .Left = 400
    End With

Nutbreite2 = (Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("C4").Value)
    Set Nut2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Shapes("Gruppieren 12")
    With Nut2
        .Width = Nutbreite2
        .Left = 400
    End With

 End sub
```

Thus I repeat that for 16 reactangles which is a pretty stupid solution. But as I am a beginner after hours I don't get it better.
I think there are two possible solutions:
1. Either make 2 lists/arrays a la {Nut1, Nut2...} and use the with function each once
2. or define 2 subs in the beginning with the parameters for a rectangle and call them later.

I have tried for hours both options but didn't get along. The simple solution Nut = Nut2 doesn't work neither... :(
 The question is: how can I reduce the 16 "With...End With" expressions if they all have the same parameters but adress differenct rectangles??

Comment: `Nut = Nut2` won't work because you literally set it equal to the same object in memory. Thus, when one changes, the other will change also. I'd recommend writing another method that takes a shape and a double as a parameter.

Comment: yes sounds good, but how do I do that? there are several methods but none working... :/

Comment: What is your code trying to accomplish? Are you creating the shapes or resizing them? Or are you trying to just create a list of the eight shapes in VBA for use someplace else?

Comment: The code is just supposed to resize the shapes. I have already created them in Excel.

Comment: In my sheet I have the shapes which width and heigt I type into cells. Then I click on a command button and all of the shapes are resized at once.

Comment: Post the code you wrote for your subroutine and your attempt to call them. I'm sure you'll get several suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about the names of your rectangles and the order they are in. I have the following code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim i, j, k As Integer
    Dim width As Double

    j = 3 'Cell value locator
    k = 9 'Increment shape names, assumption "Gruppieren 10", "Gruppieren 12", "Gruppieren 14", etc

    For i = 1 To 16

        If Not i Mod 2 = 0 Then

            width = (Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("C" + Trim(Str(j)).Value)) ' grab the value from C3

        Else

            width = (Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("C" + Trim(Str(j + 1)).Value)) ' grab the value from C4

        End If

        AlterRectangle width, "Gruppieren " + Trim(Str(k + i))

        k = k + 1

    Next i

End Sub


Private Sub AlterRectangle(width As Double, shapeName As Integer)

    Dim Nut As Shape
    Set Nut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").shapes(shapeName)
    With Nut
        .Width = width
        .Left = 400
    End With

End Sub
```

This makes shape G10, G14, G18, and G22 width the C3 value and G12, G16, G20, and G24 width the C4 value.

It may be better to make the names different on your shapes themselves so that it would be easier to specify which one needs a certain size.

**Update** per your comment:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim width As Double
    Dim group1() As String, group2() As String
    Dim name As String

    group1 = Split("Gruppieren 10,Gruppieren 14,Gruppieren 18,Gruppieren 22", ",")
    group2 = Split("Gruppieren 12,Gruppieren 16,Gruppieren 20,Gruppieren 24", ",")

    For Each name In group1
        width = (Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("C3").Value) ' grab the value from C3
        AlterRectangle width, name
    Next name

    For Each name In group2
        width = (Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("C4").Value) ' grab the value from C4
        AlterRectangle width, name
    Next name

End Sub


Private Sub AlterRectangle(width As Double, shapeName As Integer)

    Dim Nut As Shape
    Set Nut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Shapes(shapeName)
    With Nut
        .width = width
        .Left = 400
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! but isn't it just easier to create 2 groups with the specific names of the shapes (shape1, shape 2...) and define for each group the width?

Comment: depends on what the names are. if they are as i assumed then the code should work either way. if they aren't then the grouping would be better, I'll post an update shortly

Comment: When I say depends what the names are, if you follow a naming convention and want to add 250 more shapes, the first code would be much better than hardcoding all 258 names in two arrays. But if you know for a fact that you'll only ever have 8 boxes then hardcoding names works fine.

Comment: thanks for the update! Did you try the code? I get an error message that it cannot assign values to the groups? :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can organize the code to resize the shape sizes:

> UPDATE: that's what I get for writing and posting without test. the modified code below works

```
Option Explicit

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim tabelleWB As Workbook
    Dim tabelleWS As Worksheet
    Set tabelleWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set tabelleWS = tabelleWB.Sheets("Tabelle1")

    Dim nutBreiteA As Long
    Dim nutBreiteB As Long
    nutBreiteA = tabelleWS.Range("C3")
    nutBreiteB = tabelleWS.Range("C4")

    '--- assign shapes to groups using the name of the shape
    Dim gruppierenA() As String
    Dim gruppierenB() As String
    gruppierenA = Split("Gruppieren 1,Gruppieren 2,Gruppieren 3,Gruppieren 4", ",")
    gruppierenB = Split("Gruppieren 5,Gruppieren 6,Gruppieren 7,Gruppieren 8", ",")

    SetShapeSize tabelleWS, gruppierenA, nutBreiteA
    SetShapeSize tabelleWS, gruppierenB, nutBreiteB

End Sub

Sub SetShapeSize(ws As Worksheet, shapeNames() As String, newSize As Long)
    Dim shapeName As Variant
    Dim thisShape As Shape
    For Each shapeName In shapeNames
        Set thisShape = ws.Shapes(shapeName)
        thisShape.Width = newSize
        thisShape.Left = 400
    Next shapeName
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I get several error messages.. the first is a problem with the SetShapeSize() as String type. The error message says it is supposed to be Variant. After changing that, the next error is about the data type in Dim gruppierenA() As String...? :/ Another question is, where is the CommandButton_Click() ?

Comment: Sorry but the code is not working I have tried to edit it... :/